# Disable T3 on weblogic

Tags: jakarta-ee, weblogic

I'm wondering how I could **disable T3 service on weblogic Server**.
I've looked around but I didn't find any documentation on this.

It would be helpful if some body can point some solutions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Weblogic 11g and 12c are impacted by T3 protocol vulnerability, thus the question is important: https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-93/product_id-14534/version_id-187486/Oracle-Weblogic-Server-12.2.1.0.html

Answer (score 0):

You can't disable it. But here's two things you can do:

1. Set up [Connection Filtering](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24485/con_filtr.htm#SCPRG377) to block t3 and t3s
2. Change the default port number and create a new http-only [channel](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24432/network.htm#CNFGD180) on the default port